# Send Multicast Message to a group

Tags: udp, multicast

I created a chat with two types for conversations: Private (***Unicast***) and Group(***Multicast***, i have to use multicast).

I have to make different groups (i.e. i join at group **"Veterans"** and my college join at the group **"Beginners"**). The messages that send and receive at group "Veterans" can't be received at group **"Beginners"**.

For this, my question is: i have to create different multicast groups? Or verify, if the message that is sent by user, is for group **"Veterans"** or **"Beginners**, for example by the name of the group?

Answer (score 0):

You don't **have** to use multicast to achieve this, but from what I am hearing, it might be a sound design decision to make.

Multicast being what it is, having separate multicast groups help will split the flows at a logical level, but not necessarily at the network level.

Furthermore, you need to have functionality in your application that translates a group name (e.g. "Veterans") to a multicast address. This mapping needs to be kept in complete sync between all your chat clients or else there might be "cross-chatter".

> "The messages that send and receive at group 'Veterans' can't be
>   received at group 'Beginners'".

The key word here is **can't**. Multicast will keep the flows separate, but from a security perspective it will only keep casual users from eavesdropping on an unauthorized group. Setting a network card on the same subnet in promiscuous mode will reveal all multicast conversations while staying completely undetected.

So if you are looking for an absolute guarantee for **"can't"**, multicast will not be sufficient.